# Get column number of checkbox on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to get the table column number of a checkbox when selected

Below is the code I have been trying, but it returns 0.  How would be best to do this?

```js
 $(document).on('change', '.select_all_checkbox', function() {
        var columnNo = $(this).index();
        alert(columnNo);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please provide more information and your html. There are many ways to achieve something like that and for me it's not exactly clear what you're trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns zero because `index()` with no argument returns index of that element within it's siblings and that checkbox likely has no siblings

You want the index of the parent `<td>`

```
var columnNo = $(this).parent().index();
// OR
var columnNo = $(this).closest('td').index();
```